# Is the functional $E: L^2[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$, $E(f) = \|f\|_2^2$, continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis

If I define the functional $E \colon L^2[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ by $E(f) = \|f\|_2^2$, is this functional continuous?

Initially, I was thinking of using the fact that a linear operator is continuous if and only if it is bounded. However, this functional $E$ is not linear, so this theorem does not apply.

I tried and $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument, but it does not seem to work out. Could anyone help?

Comment: $L^{2}[0, 1]$ is a Hilbert space, and the functional $E$ is, in fact, the scalar product $f \mapsto (f, f)_{L^2}$ in that Hilbert space.  So,
$$
E(f + \epsilon) = (f + \epsilon, f + \epsilon) = ||f||_{2}^{2} + 2(f, \epsilon) + ||\epsilon||_{2}^{2}
$$
Now compute the difference $E(f + \epsilon) - E(f)$ and estimate its norm.

Comment: Continuous **iff** continuous is vacuously true :-).

Comment: @copper.hat I think OP meant continuous iff bounded operator.

Comment: @HenryW. Yes, I changed that. Plus this was a super simple question that I just failed to think through this late in the night...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Establish the following facts:

1. In a normed vector space $(X,\lVert\cdot\rVert)$, the norm $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ in the norm topology is continuous.
2. The square of any continuous function is continuous.

Then plug in $X = L^2[0,1]$, $\lVert\cdot\rVert=\lVert\cdot\rVert_2$

Answer (score 1):

The norm is continuous since all norms satisfy
$| \|x\| - \|y\| | \le \|x-y\|$ and the function $t \mapsto t^2$ is continuous, hence so is the composition.

This is true in any normed space.